# Client side timeout when download the large file using NSURLSession in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, download, nsurlsession, large-files

Currently I am downloading large files (500 MB) to the device using below codes. But always timeout happened in client side in 65 - 85 seconds. Why it happens? 
Because of this reason I reduced the file size to 50 MB and download separate URLs in for loop and its working fine. But if it is poor internet connection, I will face same timeout issue. Hoc can I Fix it?

```
-(void)downloadFileToDevice:(NSString *)stringURL
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"myUniqueAppID"];

    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 6000;
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 6000;

    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:600];
    task1 = [_session downloadTaskWithRequest:request ];
    [task1 resume];
    saveUrlname = [stringURL lastPathComponent];
    NSString *tempPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingString:@"/Downloads/Databases/TempZip/Temp"];
    NSString *filePath = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveUrlname];

    do {
        if (downloadError == 1) {
            break;
        }        
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
    } while (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);    
}
```

Below is the delegate method to write file to device.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
     NSString *tempPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingString:@"/Downloads/Databases/TempZip/Temp"];
    NSString *filePath = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveUrlname];


    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:location.path
                                            toPath:filePath
                                             error:nil];

}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have the do while loop with the sleep in it? Use `downloadTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` instead.

Comment: Learn `NSURLSession` [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: @trapper do while loop used for sync download. That is not the issue for the timeout.

Comment: Are you sure?  If this is blocking the main thread for that long, your process will get killed.

Comment: @dgatwood I download 50MB URLs (25 urls) in a loop and it is working fine.